# A thread can't properly remove itself from a List. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

When I try to get accustomed with a new library or concept, I typically do a small toy project that utilizes those libraries or concepts. `java.util.concurrent` is no different. I only start to learn that library so I made a few simple apps. Some of them work, but this one (it was supposed to teach me to get comfortable with `Semaphore`) misbehaves. Here's the complete code. It's not minimal, but since I don't know which part I can safely cut (except for `River`, `speed`, but it's not much code anyway), I decided to include it in its entirety

```java
public record River(short width) {
}
```

```java
public interface Status {
    String description();
}
```

```java
public abstract class StatusReporter extends Thread {
    protected Status status;
    public StatusReporter(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void setAndReportStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
        System.out.println(getName() + ": " + status.description());
    }
}
```

```java
public class SharedSynchronizers {
    static final Lock FAIR_LOCK = new ReentrantLock(true);
    static final Condition CONDITION = FAIR_LOCK.newCondition();
}
```

```java
public class Boat {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private final byte capacity;
    @Getter
    private final byte speed;
    private final List<Passenger> passengersOnBoard;
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final Condition condition = SharedSynchronizers.CONDITION;

    private Boat(Builder builder) {
        capacity = builder.capacity;
        speed = builder.speed;
        passengersOnBoard = builder.passengersOnBoard;
        semaphore = builder.semaphore;
    }

    public static Builder withCapacity(byte capacity) {
        return new Builder(capacity);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private final byte capacity;
        private byte speed;
        private final List<Passenger> passengersOnBoard;
        private final Semaphore semaphore;

        private Builder(byte capacity) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.passengersOnBoard = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
            this.semaphore = new Semaphore(capacity, true);
        }

        public Boat andSpeed(byte speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
            return new Boat(this);
        }
    }

    void addPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        try {
            while (semaphore.availablePermits() < 1) {
                condition.await(); // so that a thread releases a lock if it can't acquire a permit
            }
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        passengersOnBoard.add(passenger);
    }

    void removePassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        passengersOnBoard.remove(passenger);
    }

    boolean hasPassengers() {
        return !passengersOnBoard.isEmpty();
    }

    boolean isFull() {
        return passengersOnBoard.size() == capacity;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Passenger extends StatusReporter {
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private BoatKeeper boatKeeper;
    private static final short EMBARK_DISEMBARK_TIME = 500;
    private final Lock lock = SharedSynchronizers.FAIR_LOCK;
    private final Condition condition = SharedSynchronizers.CONDITION;

    public Passenger(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        tryToGetOnBoat();
        stayOnBoat();
        disembark();
    }

    private void tryToGetOnBoat() {
        setAndReportStatus(PassengerStatus.GOING_TO_EMBARK);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(EMBARK_DISEMBARK_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        lock.lock();
        boatKeeper.getBoat().addPassenger(this);
        boatKeeper.getPassengersToFerry().remove(this);
        setAndReportStatus(PassengerStatus.EMBARKED_THE_BOAT);
        condition.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    private void stayOnBoat() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            while (!boatKeeper.isRowing()) {
                condition.await();
            }
            lock.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        setAndReportStatus(PassengerStatus.CROSSING_THE_RIVER);
    }

    private void disembark() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            while (!boatKeeper.isDisembarking()) {
                condition.await();
            }
            lock.unlock();
            Thread.sleep(EMBARK_DISEMBARK_TIME);
            boatKeeper.getBoat().removePassenger(this);
            lock.lock();
            condition.signalAll();
            lock.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        setAndReportStatus(PassengerStatus.ON_THE_OTHER_BANK);
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    enum PassengerStatus implements Status {
        GOING_TO_EMBARK("going to embark the boat..."),
        EMBARKED_THE_BOAT("embarked the boat!"),
        WAITING_FOR_OTHER_PASSENGERS("waiting for other passengers to join..."),
        CROSSING_THE_RIVER("crossing the river..."),
        ON_THE_OTHER_BANK("on the other bank!");

        private final String description;

        @Override
        public String description() {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class BoatKeeper extends StatusReporter {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private final Boat boat;
    private int timeToCrossRiver;
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private final List<Passenger> passengersToFerry = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Lock lock = SharedSynchronizers.FAIR_LOCK;
    private final Condition condition = SharedSynchronizers.CONDITION;

    public BoatKeeper(Boat boat) {
        super("Boat keeper");
        this.boat = boat;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        performFerrying();
    }

    public BoatKeeper ferry(Passenger... passengers) {
        Collections.addAll(passengersToFerry, passengers);
        return this;
    }

    public void acrossRiver(River river) {
        timeToCrossRiver = river.width() / boat.getSpeed();
        start();
    }

    private void performFerrying() {
        invitePassengersToEmbark();
        while (hasFerryingToDo()) {
            waitTillBoatReadyToGo();
            crossRiver();
            disembarkPassengers();
            rowBack();
        }
        setAndReportStatus(BoatKeeperStatus.DONE);
    }

    private void invitePassengersToEmbark() {
        passengersToFerry.forEach(p -> {
            p.setBoatKeeper(this);
            p.start();
        });
    }

    private void waitTillBoatReadyToGo() {
        if (!isBoardingComplete()) {
            setAndReportStatus(BoatKeeperStatus.WAITING_FOR_PASSENGERS_TO_EMBARK);
        }
        try {
            lock.lock();
            while (!isBoardingComplete()) {
                condition.await();
            }
            lock.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void crossRiver() {
        setAndReportStatus(BoatKeeperStatus.FERRYING_PASSENGERS);
        lock.lock();
        condition.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeToCrossRiver);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void disembarkPassengers() {
        setAndReportStatus(BoatKeeperStatus.DISEMBARKING_PASSENGERS);
        lock.lock();
        condition.signalAll();
        try {
            while (boat.hasPassengers()) {
                condition.await();
            }
            lock.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void rowBack() {
        setAndReportStatus(BoatKeeperStatus.RETURNING);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeToCrossRiver);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        lock.lock();
        /*
        doesn't matter if the boat keeper releases more permits than 
        the number of passengers it ferried: if it's less than the boat's
        max capacity, then it was the last trip anyway
        */
        boat.getSemaphore().release(boat.getCapacity());
        condition.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    private boolean hasFerryingToDo() {
        return !passengersToFerry.isEmpty() || boat.hasPassengers();
    }

    private boolean isBoardingComplete() {
        return boat.isFull() ||
                (boat.hasPassengers() && passengersToFerry.isEmpty());
    }

    boolean isRowing() {
        return status == BoatKeeperStatus.FERRYING_PASSENGERS;
    }

    boolean isDisembarking() {
        return status == BoatKeeperStatus.DISEMBARKING_PASSENGERS;
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    enum BoatKeeperStatus implements Status {
        WAITING_FOR_PASSENGERS_TO_EMBARK("waiting for passengers to embark..."),
        FERRYING_PASSENGERS("ferrying passengers across the river..."),
        DISEMBARKING_PASSENGERS("disembarking passengers..."),
        RETURNING("returning..."),
        DONE("all passengers are ferried!");
        private final String description;

        @Override
        public String description() {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        River river = new River((short) 2800);
        Boat tinyBoat = Boat.withCapacity((byte) 2).andSpeed((byte) 10);
        BoatKeeper boatKeeper = new BoatKeeper(tinyBoat);
        Passenger[] passengers = {
                new Passenger("Frank"), new Passenger("Liz"), new Passenger("Gabriel")
        };
        boatKeeper.ferry(passengers).acrossRiver(river);
    }
}
```

Behavior varies. Whether you run it with or without the IntelliJ IDEA debugger seems to have some effect, but it's not a fail-proof predictor either

**Scenario #1: Ghost passenger** (typical without the debugger, unless it's attached after the freeze)

The passenger threads disembark and finish, but the boat still has one `null` element making the boat keeper wait indefinitely and not row back.

```
Boat keeper: waiting for passengers to embark...
Frank: going to embark the boat...
Liz: going to embark the boat...
Gabriel: going to embark the boat...
Frank: embarked the boat!
Liz: embarked the boat!
Boat keeper: ferrying passengers across the river...
Liz: crossing the river...
Frank: crossing the river...
Boat keeper: disembarking passengers...
Liz: on the other bank!
Frank: on the other bank!

// freezes!
```

[screenshot showing that there's some null passenger on the boat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFb9y.png)

**Scenario #2: Everything is fine** (typically with the debugger, rarely without)

No issues observed

```
Gabriel: going to embark the boat...
Liz: going to embark the boat...
Frank: going to embark the boat...
Boat keeper: waiting for passengers to embark...
Frank: embarked the boat!
Liz: embarked the boat!
Boat keeper: ferrying passengers across the river...
Frank: crossing the river...
Liz: crossing the river...
Boat keeper: disembarking passengers...
Frank: on the other bank!
Liz: on the other bank!
Boat keeper: returning...
Gabriel: embarked the boat!
Boat keeper: ferrying passengers across the river...
Gabriel: crossing the river...
Boat keeper: disembarking passengers...
Gabriel: on the other bank!
Boat keeper: returning...
Boat keeper: all passengers are ferried!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Since I can't reproduce the issue while debugging the program, I'm completely at a loss. **Why do those freezes happen? How do I fix it so that I get the second scenario all the time?**

I debugged thoroughly, spent a lot of hours trying to pinpoint the issue. I don't see any other choice but to ask for your help

Comment: At a glance, this looks like a standard thread safety issue caused by trying to concurrently modify a non-thread-safe collection without any sort of locking.  Modifications to things like ArrayLists need to be done under a lock.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you! It seems to have a positive effect. But why don't I get `ConcurrentModificationException` or the like? I know that `ExecutorService` "swallows" exceptions, but I don't use it here

Comment: Also, why is there some weird `null` element? Shouldn't the removal be atomic in the sense "it either happens completely or not at all"? Was there some swallowed exception between nullifying the removed element's index and `size--`?

Comment: Why are you extending Thread... with an abstract class? I'm surprised the compiler lets you do that. What is the abstract method? This is horrible.

Comment: In the code you have provided, addPassenger is only ever called on "this", this can never be null. The problem you're seeing is not caused by the existing code.

Comment: @matt it's pretty straightforward: I want to avoid code duplication since both `Passenger` and `BoatKeeper` share report functionality. As far as I know, there's nothing inherently wrong with having an abstract class as a `Thread` child. Abstract classes are classes that can't be instantiated, that's it. `StatusReporter` doesn't make sense on its own so it's reasonable to make it abstract

Comment: @matt as a matter of fact, it *was* caused by the existing code. See the answer below

Comment: @JoreJoh: No, who promised that changes to `ArrayList` would be atomic?  The documentation specifically _doesn't_ promise that.  Every single operation you need to do to an `ArrayList` needs to use a lock, and it needs to be the same lock.

Comment: @JoreJoh I don't see how the answer says why your array list contains null. Maybe since your in a threaded environment with a debugger you've captured a transient state where null is in the list.

Comment: In general you shouldn't extend Thread. Also, when you extend something, the thing your extend is the parent. "StatusReporter doesn't make sense on its own so it's reasonable to make it abstract" It's not clear *why* that is the case. If doesn't make sense on it's own, then dont give it a public constructor. Use protected constructor, then it would need to be extended. Really it doesn't need to be a class at all, an interface should work.

Comment: Re, "why don't I get `ConcurrentModificationException`...?" That exception is poorly named. The JRE doesn't raise it because of anything to do with threads. It is raised when your program tries to use an `Iterator` after the Iterator has been invalidated by the program mutating the `Collection` to which the Iterator belongs. The kinds of errors that are caused by threads accessing shared variables with no synchronization are practically impossible to _reliably_ detect and identify. You cannot count on threading errors to cause _meaningful_ exceptions.

Comment: @matt no, it wouldn't work since interfaces can't have instance fields. In this case, `status` is an instance field

Comment: @SolomonSlow but was there any exception at all? If so, was it swallowed?

Comment: You want your object to extend thread, and you want your object to extend status report. So you've made StatusReport extend Thread. You want StatusReport to be abstract because you don't think it makes sense to exist on its own. I'm definitely a fan of composition over inheritance. Your class could just have an instance of StatusReport and implement Runnable. But you're right, it is pretty much just practice.

Comment: Re, "was there any exception at all?" A "race condition" (result of unsynchronized access to shared variables) could cause some kind of data corruption or it could cause some kind of logic error. It could affect your own program's data/logic, it could affect the JRE, or it could affect the JVM. Literally _anything_ could happen; It could cause an immediate program crash (e.g., "segfault"), it could cause a "glitch" in the GUI, it could cause your program to write an incorrect value to a record in a database that you don't discover until months later. Literally, _anything_ could happen.

Comment: P.S., "_Could_ cause..." For example, in a big, commercial, back-end system, it might _not_ cause any of the above during weeks of testing, and then months later, after being released into the field, it could cause a major problem on some client's web site. (Ask me some time how much fun it is to do a post-mortem on a client's four gigabyte core-file when the debug symbols for that release have somehow gone missing.)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note.** It's not my answer but rather the answer [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) gave in the comments (apparently, he doesn't want to post it as an answer).*

> At a glance, this looks like a standard thread safety issue caused by trying to concurrently modify a non-thread-safe collection without any sort of locking. Modifications to things like ArrayLists need to be done under a lock.
>
> *–Louis Wasserman*

Indeed, changing this part of `disembark()` method

```java
            boatKeeper.getBoat().removePassenger(this);
            lock.lock();
            condition.signalAll();
            lock.unlock();
```

to this

```java
            lock.lock();
            boatKeeper.getBoat().removePassenger(this);
            condition.signalAll();
            lock.unlock();
```

helped. Thank you!

Comment: "If you find it useful, upvote some of Louis Wasserman's other answers instead" really not trying to be rude or anything, but by SO rules, you shouldn't suggest that people do that - it counts as serial upvoting iirc, and just because you found his comment/answer in this post useful doesn't mean that extends to all his others.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget is it legal to delete it repost it as a Community answer now? I now seem to possess that privilege

Comment: I think there's a checkbox that appears when you edit called "make community post"

Comment: As an aside, put the `unlock()`s in a finally block, to ensure it always gets called.

Comment: @AndyTurner I wanted to release the lock as soon as possible to avoid any freezes

Comment: Please don't upvote my other answers.  (In all honesty, I post in the comments when I don't feel like taking the time to write a thorough answer, and you are welcome to expand them into a more complete answer.)

Comment: @JoreJoh put the try/finally just around the portion where you want the lock to be held. So, `lock(); try { /* do stuff with lock */ } finally { unlock(); }`.

Comment: @AndyTurner are you sure it's necessary at all? From the JLS: *"If execution of the body is ever completed, either normally **or abruptly** [presumably, e.g. due to an exception], an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor."*

Comment: @JoreJoh that's referring to a `synchronized` statement, unlocking the monitor object on which you are synchronizing. I don't see you using a `synchronized` statement here.

Comment: @JoreJoh see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=253